# Best form to make a map of related strings on JavaScript ES6?

Tags: javascript, gulp, ecmascript-6, object-literal

I use gulp to manage all my assets of websites. I migrated all my code to ES6. You can see my starter gulpfile here: https://github.com/ramasilveyra/solid-webapp/blob/master/gulpfile.babel.js

And I have doubts whether this is the best way to handle the paths of all differents assets. There is a better form (more practical without functions)? Thanks!

```js
const paths = {
    src: './src',
    dist: './dist',
    assets: {
        src: paths.src + '/assets',
        dist: paths.dist + '/assets'
    },
    scripts: {
        src: () => paths.assets.src + '/scripts',
        dist: () => paths.assets.dist + '/scripts'
    },
    styles: {
        src: () => paths.assets.src + '/styles',
        dist: () => paths.assets.dist + '/styles'
    },
    media: {
        src: () => paths.assets.src + '/media',
        dist: () => paths.assets.dist + '/media'
    },
    fonts: {
        src: () => paths.assets.src + '/fonts',
        dist: () => paths.assets.dist + '/fonts'
    }
};
```

Comment: `paths.assets.src == "undefined/assets"`?

Comment: Looks like a loop would be suited here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ES6 will not bring something new for you. But you can split filling object into few statements:

```
const paths = {
   src: './src',
   dist: './dist'
};
paths.assets = {
    src: paths.src + '/assets',
    dist: paths.dist + '/assets'
};
paths.scripts = {
    src: () => paths.assets.src + '/scripts',
    dist: () => paths.assets.dist + '/scripts'
};
// ... and so on
```

Note that object defined via `const` can be modified in the further operations. If you want prevent changes of any its field, call `Object.freeze(paths)` after your assignments.